# Send Push Notification to All Platforms

Tags: php, azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Push Notifications Hub that devices from all platforms register on.

My backend is written in PHP and looking at their docs, it seems that you need to push a notification for each individual platform.

```
$alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("apple", $alert);
$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

[Source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-php-push-notification-tutorial.md)

Is there a way to send to all platforms in one call?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear so no, you'll have to create a `Notification` object for each platform you want to send to, as they use different message formats:

From your source link:

**For iOS**

```
$alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("apple", $alert);
$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

**For Kindle Fire**

```
$message = '{"data":{"msg":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("adm", $message);
$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

**For Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 Silverlight**

```
$toast = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' .
            '<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">' .
               '<wp:Toast>' .
                    '<wp:Text1>Hello from PHP!</wp:Text1>' .
               '</wp:Toast> ' .
            '</wp:Notification>';
$notification = new Notification("windowsphone", $toast);
$notification->headers[] = 'X-WindowsPhone-Target : toast';
$notification->headers[] = 'X-NotificationClass : 2';
$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

**For Android**

```
$message = '{"data":{"msg":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("gcm", $message);
$hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
```

Note: As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. 

You should use Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android from now on: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/